# Is it possible to host R shiny app on AWS Lambda

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny

I've never seen any documentation about this and I'm planning on trying it for myself and documenting it if it works.

But the question is, can you host an R Shiny app on just AWS Lambda? A dynamic app where a user can enter inputs, use reactives, render new plots...etc.

Say for example we have this function which is an R shiny app

```
binner <- function(var) {
  require(shiny)
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(sliderInput("n", "Bins", 5, 100, 20)),
        mainPanel(plotOutput("hist"))
      )
    ), 
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$hist <- renderPlot( 
        hist(var, breaks = input$n,
          col = "skyblue", border = "white") 
      )
    }
  )
}
```

We then call this function from any of the runtimes AWS Lambda supports such as Python, would this work?

Comment: The lifetime on AWS lambda is [15 minutes](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/). Now I dont think it is possible (as I dont think they have a public port), but if anything the lifetime is a clear "this is not a good idea" :-)

Comment: you'd need a custom runtime. see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-walkthrough.html

Comment: @Oliver I'm aware the lifetime is 15 minutes, "this is not a good idea" entirely depends on the web app. In my case 15 minutes is perfect and the fact that lambda now supports 10gb memory and 6 vCPU's would be amazing for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan yes I'm aware I need a custom runtime and I've read that before. As I mentioned at the bottom of the question calling the function from another language.